# OpenFileDialod CLR/C++ зависает при вызове

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Создал обычную форму в CLR/C++. Добавил элемент OpenFileDialog и кнопку
При вызове кнопки прописал openFileDialog->ShowDialog();
Итог - зависает вся программа и просто критически завершается
Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Не должно. У вас там нигде нет бесконечной рекурсии? Покажите код.

Comment: private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
  openFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
 }
Автоматически созданная кнопка... Просто вызываю метод. Ошибок не подсвечивает... Просто все зависает

Comment: Странно, а может, это какой-нибудь антивирус шалит? Попробуйте этот же код на другой машине.

Comment: Попробовал - не помогло! Все также.. Может проблема в создании самого окна... Делаю это через:
Project::MyForm form;
Application::Run(%form);

Comment: Ого! А почему не через `gcnew`? Хотя по идее должно работать и так, да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось элементарно! Просто подключить STAThread